# Significance of a capital R outside of brackets containing a matrix expression

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I was trying to understand what a positive definite matrix is while reading a reinforcement learning paper today, and I came across this page: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PositiveDefiniteMatrix.html

The first equation is the one I'm referring to with my question. Does this notation simply mean the real part of the complex matrix that results by evaluating the expression inside the brackets?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that means real part.  It's hard to see, but it's probably supposed to be a "fancy" $$\huge \Re$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Does one find the real part of a matrix simply by ignoring the complex part, or is there a process for integrating the complex part into the real part and ending up with purely real numbers that still contain all of the information in the complex part.

Comment: @RichardWilliams: The first line is not taking the real part of a matrix; it's taking the real part of $x^* Ax$, which is a scalar.  Taking the real part of a matrix could mean taking the real part of each entry; it's also used to denote the different operation $\frac{1}{2} (A+A^*)$, by analogy with the fact that the real part of a complex number is given by $\frac{1}{2} (z+\bar{z})$.  Either way information is lost.

Comment: Thanks Nate! Sorry it took me so long to see this response. I really appreciate the insight, though clearly I needed (and still need) to build a lot of foundational math knowledge before I tackle more RL problems.